# Kickstart %post issue

Tags: bash, pxe-boot, kickstart

I'm configuring a kickstart profile and I'd like to create some script file.

I'm doing like this:

```
cat <<EOF >>/scripts/myfile.pl
#!/usr/bin/perl
...
my $int;
`useradd me`;
...
EOF
```

After the PXE boot and installation process, when I check the file, everything starting with "$", and line starting with backquote disappeared.

Back-slashing backquotes seems to have worked, but not $.

Is there a way to make this work ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try: cat <<'EOF' >>/scripts/myfile.pl

This is a parameter substitution issue.